# Basic authentification issue through XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, basic-authentication

I am trying to call an [OutPan](https://www.outpan.com/) service to get barcode details.

```
var url = "https://api.outpan.com/v1/products/0796435419035";
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var encodedString = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:";
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedString);
xmlhttp.send();
var temp = xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

encodedString is the API key Base64 conversion. Converting string to Base64 is not straightforward in Javascript. I have converted it using online tool and assigned that value to encodedString. However I get:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
>
> Reader.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.outpan.com/v1/products/0796435419035. Invalid HTTP status code 401

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting the colon and the (empty) password.

The format for basic authetication is `"Basic " + base64(username + ":" + password)`, so you need to encode your api key followed by a colon.